# How to get next month's date from the current date using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently showing the current month but would like to show next month's date using the current date.  Also i like to show the December month.
Example: November - 2015 and also December - 2015.  This is the current month:

```
  <%=DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM - yyyy") %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should read the Microsoft documentation on DateTime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add one month to current date.

```
<%=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMMM - yyyy") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMMM - yyyy") %>
```